# Отсортируйте value в алфавитном порядке. Сортирует всё

Tags: python, сортировка

```
def sort_dictionary(dict: dict) -> dict: 
  return sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

print(sort_dictionary({"b": [], "a": [], "c": []}))  # = > {"b": [], "a": [], "c": []}
print(sort_dictionary({"": ["a", "f", "d"]}))  # = > {"": ["a", "d", "f"]}
print(sort_dictionary({"b": ["d", "a"], "a": ["c", "f"]}))  # = > {"b": ["a", "d"], "a": ["c", "f"]}
print(sort_dictionary({"Jack": ["swimming", "hiking"], "Charlie": ["games", "yoga"]}))  # = > {"Jack": ["hiking", "swimming"], "Charlie": ["games", "yoga"]}
```

Отсортируйте value в алфавитном порядке. Порядок key не важен.

1. Не понимаю как сделать, чтобы выдавал ответ в dict формате
2. Начинает сортировать всё, а не только value.

Comment: вам надо отсортировать списки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по комментариям, вам надо отсортировать списки, которые являются значениями в словаре

```
def sort_dictionary(d: dict) -> dict:
  return {k:sorted(v) for k,v in d.items()}
```

Не называйте переменные именами встроенных типов!